# Is there a way to automatically restart nodejs app after a 503 error?

Tags: node.js, websocket, shared-hosting, pusher

My nodejs app keeps getting 503 resource exceed error every few weeks after running so I need to keep restarting it via ssh. I was wondering if there is something I can install to automatically restart it whenever I get an error or it crashes.

I have checked our A2Hosting server's number of processes during the error but it just says 0/50.

I am using pusher real time.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const Pusher = require("pusher");

var pusher = new Pusher({
  appId: "xxxxxx",
  key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  secret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  cluster: "ap1",
  encrypted: true
});

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const newVote = {
    id: req.body.id,
    points: 1
  };

  pusher.trigger("scan", "scan-player", {
    id: req.body.id,
    player_id: req.body.player_id,
    admin_id: req.body.admin_id
  });

  return res.json({
    success: true,
    message: "Scan successful!",
    id: req.body.id
   });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An error should not get your app to crash, you should handle it and just log the error message. For example, with [express error handler](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html), see : *[error handling patterns with express](https://gist.github.com/zcaceres/2854ef613751563a3b506fabce4501fd)*

Also, if your app crash, some programs can restart it automatically. The most basic one is *[forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever)* :

```
forever start app.js
```

It restarts your app when it crashes. But the best one in my opinion is *[pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/)* :

```
pm2 start app.js
```

It does the same, but has a lot of additional functionalities, like load balancing, deployment system, log managment

Hope it helps,
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

If you can configure cron jobs on your server then write a script which checks your logs for failure and restarts the app if it finds 503 error and attach the script to a cron job.

script can be like

```
if [ grep -q "503 or something specific" $logfile ]; then {
    service $whatever stop;
    service $whatever start;
} fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If planning to try the cron job/script suggestion, then you would need to finally purge the log file after restart otherwise this would result in a restart loop.

There is a tool called logrotate which is cron implemented itself, you can add your own configurataion files to /etc/logrotate.d

IMHO the best option by far is pm2 as suggested. It really is the best and easiest of the process managers.